# Writing video raw data into string with php

Tags: php, raw-data

I am trying to use an API, Bunny Stream API, they require that I upload using raw binary data. I have been using file_get_contents() and this works fine for smaller files. Files under 100mb. But this stop working with bigger files. I read online that file_get_contents fails since there isn't enough memory for it to read files as big as 1gb. So I saw that streams were a thing and tried coming up with this solution

```
try{
        $handle = fopen($video_path, 'rb');
        $buffer = '';
        if($handle){
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $buffer .= fgets($handle);    
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo json_encode("FAILED");
        exit();
    }
```

But this also isn't working and is also unable to throw an error. I can't seem to understand what's happening. I was thinking it might be a configuration of some kind but still not certain.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check for timeout settings. The default is usually around 30 seconds or so, and if your file is taking longer than that to read in, it may cause a timeout.

Second : Using `$buffer .= fgets($handle);` is the same as using `file_get_contents` it will consume memory.

The solution is to send data in chunks like this:

```
try{
        $handle = fopen($video_path, 'rb');
        $buffer = '';
        if($handle){
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $buffer = fgets($handle,4096);   // 4K at a time (I guess!) 
                // send $buffer 
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo json_encode("FAILED");
        exit();
    }
```

I assume you send `$buffer` after the above code and this must change .. you send the whatever headers then start this code to send video data chunks then whatever footer to end transmitting .

**NOTE** This way does not support resume upload .. If upload fails for any reason the API will need to get data from the beginning .

```
function Bu_UploadVideo($videoId, $video_path){
    global $access_key;
    set_time_limit(0);
    try{
        $handle = fopen($video_path, 'rb');
        
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo json_encode("FAILED");
        exit();
    }
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
         CURLOPT_URL => "http://video.bunnycdn.com/library/2060/videos/$videoId",
         CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => false,
         CURLOPT_PUT => 1,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
         CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
         CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
         CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
         CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
         CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
         CURLOPT_INFILESIZE=>filesize($video_path),
         CURLOPT_INFILE=>($in=fopen($video_path, 'r')),
         CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "AccessKey: {$access_key}",
                "Content-Type: application/*+json"
            ],
        ]);
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if ($err) {return false;} 
        return true;
    }
```

***Edit from sender :*** The above is the full code for transferring over the files. I had made a few tweaks to it to see if it would work. It still isn't working.

***Me:*** I updated your code , Use `CURLOPT_INFILE`.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't provide info. The Bunny Stream API is kind of dumb honestly. I need to send the entire file as a string of data. 
"(Binary) - The video is uploaded as raw stream of data. No encoding should be specified." 
"unfortunately we don't support multipart uploads at the moment"
Yeah, so I need to get the entire buffer on one line so that I can send it there api where they do something with it. 
Kind of stuck here, but thanks for the advice. Sucks that Bunny stream is lagging behind on that front

Comment: My solution should work it just instead of loading the whole file in memory before sending, it will send on the fly. For more I need to see the code where you actually send the `$buffer` value to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I took what you provided and was able to fix it and it works 100% of the time. Thanks for the advice

```
function Bu_UploadVideo($videoId, $video_path){
    global $access_key;
    set_time_limit(0);
    try{
        
        $file = fopen($video_path, 'r');
        $filesize = filesize($video_path);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo json_encode("FAILED");
        exit();
    }
    
    
    if($file){
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://video.bunnycdn.com/library/2060/videos/$videoId",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_PUT => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_INFILE => $file,
            CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
            
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "AccessKey: {$access_key}",
                "Content-Type: application/*+json"
            ],
        ]);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        fclose($file);
        
        if ($err) {
            echo json_encode($err);
            return false;} 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```